# Export movie in specific dimensions or in the exact same dimension as the source

Tags: video, resolution, imovie, lightworks

I use iMovie 9 for simple stuff like combining videos made with my photo camera and phone. Now and then I get movies that are not in standard dimensions. I want to import and export them in the same dimensions to limit the loss of details. Using bigger dimensions or black borders is not a great solution either.

One example is that my camera (Nikon 1) has a slow motion option. It can make a 400fps movie for five seconds. It's great fun. The biggest limit is that the movie dimensions are 640x240 pixels. I want to combine several of these movies and then export them at the same dimension.

I would like to know how I can set these dimensions to the same value as the source? I won't limit my question to iMovie or iMovie 09. If I need to upgrade iMovie for this, that's OK. I've installed Lightworks, haven't done much with it yet, and this is an option as well.

Another solution would be to use Ubuntu, and I know there are some other (free) video editors out there that might do the job. I prefer a Mac solution, but if something else works, that is fine as well.

Comment: tbh, with such a tiny resolution, it will hardly make any noticeable difference.

Comment: It applies to other dimensions as well. iMovie has a limited export option. I want to use whatever the source is.

Comment: Btw, exactly **what** will make hardly any noticable difference? I think with these small dimensions everything makes a difference!

Comment: With initial dimensions so small, just expanding it to fullscreen will pull it apart so badly it really won't make any difference. That's excluding the usual colour differences between screens, it will just be 'blobby fuzzy pixels' on anything bigger than a 12" screen

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but that doesn't help me in any way. I know it's small and blowing it up doesn't make it better. I don't want to blow it up, that's the whole point of my question. Please be constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Your output options are really limited with iMovie and thats the intention... most consumers don't care about the tech details. I'm sure lightworks would have some more advanced options but I've personally never used it.

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html) is a really great (free) converter which gives you fine grained control of your output settings. The downside is it gives you *really* fine grained control of your output settings... ie its got a lot of buttons. Its geared towards the professional broadcast/ post production markets so expect to have a few goes at exporting your videos until you get it right.

[Adobe Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/mediaencoder.html) is another great tool thats geared for 'prosumers' and the top end, but it's not free. Still you can convert almost anything and it does a pretty good job. Download the trial and see if it meets your needs.

From memory there is a "match source" option with both MPEG Streamclip and Adobe Media Encoder.

You could also try [Final Cut Pro X](https://www.apple.com/au/final-cut-pro/)... I haven't personally used it (I joined the many who jumped ship after Apple ditched the professional market) however they are [making an effort to win back users](http://9to5mac.com/2013/03/28/apple-launching-final-cut-pro-x-campaign-to-win-back-skeptical-professional-users/) and I've heard some good things about it. It's certainly closer to iMovie than any of the other NLE's out there.

Comment: I'm not afraid of buttons, but don't know what I'm up against with MPEG Streamclip. I'll try it later this week. FCP will probably do all I want and a lot more, but is simple too expensive. All in all it depends on what is easier to learn, so LWKS might still be a better option.